# mac two version python conflict

Tags: python, macos

I installed python3.5 on my mac, its installation was automatically. but these days i found there was already python2 on my mac and every module i installed through pip went to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`.

I find python3 installed location is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5`

Now download a mysql-connector-python and installed it, install location is `python2.7/site-packages`, when i open pycharm whose default interceptor is python3.5, hence i can not use mysql-connector, so is there any body who know this question?

Comment: try using `pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

for mysql-connector installation problem, i found the solution:

Try go to python3 bin directory and find pip method. this pip method can be override by the system python2 pip command, so if you want to install MySQL-python module to python3.x site-packages, you should cd to such bin directory and `./pip install MySQL-python`, it can download such module successfully but installed error:`ImportError:No module named 'ConfigParser'`, I google such error and find there is no such module in python3 and we can get its fork version:`mysqlclient`.

**NOTE:** In order not to be conflict with system default python2 pip command, cd and go to python3 bin directory and `./pip install mysqlclient` and succeed.